# Is it possible to apply type constraints over a class's public methods?

Tags: typescript, class, types, constraints

I am trying to define a list of "acceptable" types that a class's public methods can return. The purpose of this is to ensure that the responses of a class's methods can be serialized via `JSON.stringify`. For example, `Map`s cannot be safely stringified and will result in `{}` being sent across the wire.

My first attempt at doing this was:

```
type TAcceptableReturns = string | number | undefined | Array<any>;

interface IReturnsAcceptable
{
    [index: string]: (() => Promise<TAcceptableReturns>) | (() => TAcceptableReturns),
}

class myActualClass implements IReturnsAcceptable
{
    [index: string]: (() => Promise<TAcceptableReturns>) | (() => TAcceptableReturns);
    private myInternalState: number;  // ERROR: Doesn't return a function

    public constructor()
    {
        this.myInternalState = 1;
    }

    public MyPubMethod(): number
    {
        return this.myInternalState;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this approach is imperfect for two core reasons:

1. It requires augmentation of the actual class's implementation (need to add `[index: string]: T`).
2. It also applies the type restrictions to the class's private properties, when I only intended for public methods/properties to be checked.

Does anyone know a way to apply constraints to all of a class's public methods/properties?

For completion's sake it would be nice if your solution can be used to not only constrain the return type but also the types of the arguments, although I don't currently have a use for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Tell TypeScript which fields should conform to your blueprint. Make `IReturnsAcceptable` generic over property names.

```
type TAcceptableReturns = string | number | undefined | Array<any>;

type IReturnsAcceptable<K extends string> = {
    [P in K]: (() => Promise<TAcceptableReturns>) | (() => TAcceptableReturns)
}

class myActualClass implements IReturnsAcceptable<'MyPubMethod'> {
    private myInternalState: number;

    public constructor() {
        this.myInternalState = 1;
    }

    public MyPubMethod(): number {
        return this.myInternalState;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Reorganize your design. Have different classes produce serializable data (as opposed to having a God-class).

```
type JSONLike =
    | { [property: string]: JSONLike }
    | readonly JSONLike[]
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null;

// JSON.stringify looks for a `toJSON` method first.
interface Serializable {
    toJSON(): JSONLike;
}
```

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
    #myInternalState: number;

    constructor() {
        this.#myInternalState = 1
    }

    toJSON() {
        return this.#myInternalState
    }
}
```

```
JSON.stringify(new MyClass().toJSON());
```

**Solution 3**

Separate your methods from other properties by grouping them in one field.

```
type TAcceptableReturns = string | number | undefined | Array<any>;

interface IReturnsAcceptable {
    methods: {
        [index: string]: (() => Promise<TAcceptableReturns>) | (() => TAcceptableReturns)
    }
}

class myActualClass implements IReturnsAcceptable {
    private myInternalState: number;

    methods = {
        MyPubMethod: () => this.myInternalState
    }

    public constructor() {
        this.myInternalState = 1;
    }
}

// Usage.
new myActualClass().methods.MyPubMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To your knowledge, is there no way to create a generic `IRemoteFriendly` interface that just ensures the class's methods arguments and return values can be serialized? Your examples require adjustment on a case by case basis, either passing in `T` or adding a `toJSON` method.

Comment: To my knowledge, it's not possible. Using index signatures (just like you did) would be the way, but there is no way to "spare" the properties that are not methods. You need to separate your methods from other properties somehow. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: `type TSafeTypes = string | number;`
`type TSafeMethods = (...arg: TSafeTypes[]) => TSafeTypes;`


If there was a way to remove the length of the array from the equation, or rather go from methodArgs -> args array, then it should be possible to create a type that stipulates that all public methods must be of type `TSafeMethods`. Something like `Class[keyof Class] extends TSafeMethods`